# Layout error for the Custom jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView

Tags: android-layout, layout, android-emulator, android

I am trying to show the image in custom `GPUImageView`. When i try to run the application into android device its working fine and doesn't show any error of layout.

But as i try to run it into emulator it shows error as below:

> ```
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.sample/jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.sample.activity.ActivityGallery}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.sample.activity.ActivityGallery.onCreate(ActivityGallery.java:49)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  ... 11 more
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView.<init>(GPUImageView.java:40)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  ... 22 more
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: OpenGL ES 2.0 is not supported on this phone.
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImage.<init>(GPUImage.java:66)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView.init(GPUImageView.java:44)
> 08-27 12:18:37.887: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  ... 26 more
> ```

**Layout File:**

> ```
>     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>       android:background="#000000"
>       android:orientation="vertical" >
> <FrameLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_weight="1" >
>     <jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView
>         android:id="@+id/gpuimage"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center" >
>         </jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView>
>     <SeekBar
>         android:id="@+id/seekBar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>         android:max="100" />
>     <FrameLayout
>         android:id="@+id/vidio"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>         <VideoView
>             android:id="@+id/vidoplayer"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>     </FrameLayout>
> </FrameLayout>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button_choose_filter"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Choose filter" />
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button_save"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Save" />
> </LinearLayout>
>  </LinearLayout>
> ```

Please guide me how can i make this thing run in emulator.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it right there:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: OpenGL ES 2.0 is not supported on this phone.

The Android emulator doesn't support OpenGL ES 2.0 yet! Check out [this link on the official site](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html) for more information.

You can take a look at [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/), it's what I use instead of the default emulator. It works way faster and supports OpenGL ES 2.0. Note that I'm not endorsing them or anything, but it's free and it works.